# Smart/Quick way to delete "one shot" all dataset of an organization?

Tags: ckan

Is there a smart/quick way to permanently delete (“purge”) "one shot" all dataset belonging to an organization, either via GUI or via sysadmin command?

I've an organization with 100k datasets ...

Answer (score 2):

In the web interface you can 'delete' an organization's datasets in large batches and then 'empty the trash' to purge them. However with so many datasets this approach may suffer from request timeouts - let us know how you get on.

As an admin for the organization:

- on the organization's page click "Manage" button
- click "Datasets" tab
- in the header row of the table tick the checkbox to select all the datasets on the page (the code suggests the paging allows you to do 500 at a time, but I've not checked for real)
- click "Delete"

Then as a sysadmin:

- In the top bar click "Sysadmin settings" (hammer icon)
- click "trash" tab
- click "Purge"

**Alternatively** you could write a script to call CKAN APIs:

- package_search for `fq=organization:<name>` (rather than using organization_show, which is limited to 1000 datasets)
- dataset_purge for each dataset

Comment: Thanks for your response.

In the past, I created a script to call CKAN APIs via Jackan http://opendatatrentino.github.io/jackan/ in order to remove a lot of datasets (more than 100k).
The problem is that 'dataset_purge' for each dataset is very slow approach if datasets are so many :-( and moreover it does not work well.
I think that CKAN developers could add also a method/facility in the GUI in order to delete "one shot" all dataset for Organization (i.e. and not just 500 at a time) by deleting them via direct query on SOLR and DB that are faster.